# Method(s) to speed up st_crop (sf package) on large datasets

Tags: r, data.table, spatial, r-sf

I need to extract information across different shapefiles for ~ 4 mio grid-cells of 1 ha. Currently I am using st_crop on each layer in a for-loop over all cells, but this runs forever. I thought to speed up the process in using a 'data.table'(DT)-sort-of-way to crop shapefiles by coordinates. Let's consider the example below, where I am looking for the extent of polygon edges in an area of interest:

```
require(sf)
require(data.table)
require(ggplot2)
require(tidyverse)

# load shapefile
nc = st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf"))


# Define a bounding-box that mimic a mowing-window or area of interest
bb <- st_bbox(c(xmin= -79, xmax=-78,ymin= 34.5, ymax= 35.5))


# Commute 'nc' into some sort of data.table object for fast subsetting, in preserving object's integrity (i.e. same id to all points of a given polygon)
nobs <- mapview::npts(nc,by_feature=T)
NC <- data.table::data.table(id=rep(1:nrow(nc),nobs),st_coordinates(nc)[,1:2])
head(NC)

# Compare cropping methods amon
library(microbenchmark)
x = runif(100)
test <- microbenchmark(
  crop_nc <- st_crop(nc,bb),
  crop_NC <- NC[X >= bb[1] & X < bb[3] & Y>= bb[2] & Y < bb[4]]
)  

print(test)
Unit: microseconds
  expr      min       lq      mean   median        uq       max neval cld
 crop_nc  5205.051 5675.807 6837.9472 5903.219 6829.0865 16046.654   100   b
 crop_NC   405.334  528.356  624.8398  576.996  656.9245  1295.361   100  a 
There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
```

As expected, the DT-way of subsetting is faster. Let's now go from our DT-object back to as sf-object as follow:

```
crop_NC_sf <- st_as_sf(crop_NC,coords=c("X","Y"),crs=st_crs(nc))  %>% group_by(id)  %>%  summarise(i=mean(id)) %>% st_cast("POLYGON")
```

Now compare the perimet of polygon's included in our study area:

```
sum(st_length(crop_nc),na.rm=T)
1307555 [m]

sum(st_length(crop_NC_sf),na.rm=T)
2610959 [m]
```

Obviously not working very well...

[image: Result]

**Questions:**

- is there another way to speed up st_crop()
- is there a way to recreate a polygon from points in preserving the 'original' order points are connected to each others?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a little more to a proper intersection via `st_intersects`(or `st_crop`) than just subsetting a bunch of coordinates. Below you will find a working solution for your example that is trying to answer both of your questions.

For question 1 I would suggest that identifying the polygons that intersect with the bbox before cropping them can in many cases speed up things quite a bit, especially if you have many polygons and the area of the bbox is small compared to the extent of the polygons area.

Regarding question 2, you can use package *sfheaders* which provides methods to create sf objects from data.frames/data.tables etc.

Finally, I reshaped the timing code a little to better reflect what each of the steps need to do to provide similar output, thus making the comparison a lot fairer.

The final result of the `data.table` way of things is different from the `st_crop` as this approach only subsets coordinates to those inside the bbox, but does not insert the coordinates of the bbox at the appropriate position. This operation is likely costly, as we need to identify these correct positions. Therefore, you will get arbitrary shapes in the result, and thing may even break as you may likely produce invalid geometries.

In general, I'd stick with the `st_crop` approach which will likely save you trouble later on. If your area of interest is big, has many polygons and the bbox you use is small in relation to the overall area, I expect that identifying the polygons that intersect with the bbox before doing the actual intersection will speed up things quite a bit.

```r
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.6.1, GDAL 2.2.3, PROJ 4.9.3
library(mapview)
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)
library(sfheaders)
library(microbenchmark)

# load shapefile
nc = st_geometry(st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf")))
#> Reading layer `nc' from data source `C:\Users\Tim\R\win-library\3.5\sf\shape\nc.shp' using driver `ESRI Shapefile'
#> Simple feature collection with 100 features and 14 fields
#> geometry type:  MULTIPOLYGON
#> dimension:      XY
#> bbox:           xmin: -84.32385 ymin: 33.88199 xmax: -75.45698 ymax: 36.58965
#> epsg (SRID):    4267
#> proj4string:    +proj=longlat +datum=NAD27 +no_defs

# Define a bounding-box that mimic a mowing-window or area of interest
bb <- st_bbox(c(xmin= -79, xmax=-78,ymin= 34.5, ymax= 35.5))
bb_sfc = st_as_sfc(bb)
st_crs(bb_sfc) <- st_crs(nc)


# Commute 'nc' into some sort of data.table object for fast subsetting, in preserving object's integrity (i.e. same id to all points of a given polygon)
nobs <- mapview::npts(nc,by_feature=T)
NC <- data.table::data.table(id=rep(1:length(nc),nobs),st_coordinates(nc)[,1:2])
head(NC)
#>    id         X        Y
#> 1:  1 -81.47276 36.23436
#> 2:  1 -81.54084 36.27251
#> 3:  1 -81.56198 36.27359
#> 4:  1 -81.63306 36.34069
#> 5:  1 -81.74107 36.39178
#> 6:  1 -81.69828 36.47178

# Compare cropping methods amon
test <- microbenchmark(
    sf_way = {
        # identify subset of nc that intersects with bbox
        isec = unlist(st_intersects(bb_sfc, nc))
        crop_nc <- st_crop(nc[isec], bb_sfc)
    }, 
    dt_way = {
        crop_NC <- NC[X >= bb[1] & X < bb[3] & Y>= bb[2] & Y < bb[4]]
        crop_NC_sf <- sfheaders::sf_polygon(crop_NC, "X", "Y", polygon_id = "id")
        st_crs(crop_NC_sf) = st_crs(nc)
    }
)  

print(test)
#> Unit: milliseconds
#>    expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
#>  sf_way 4.270801 4.492551 4.945424 4.828702 5.051951 8.666301   100   b
#>  dt_way 3.101400 3.442551 3.705610 3.593301 3.887202 8.270801   100  a

sum(st_length(crop_nc),na.rm=T)
#> 1307555 [m]
sum(st_length(crop_NC_sf),na.rm=T)
#> 975793 [m]

mapview(st_bbox(crop_nc)) + crop_NC_sf
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-11-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks Tim for your helpful comment and example. You raised great hope in introducing the 'sfheaders' package, however has you pointed out, the DT-way is likely to result in arbitrary shapes. Not much of a choice, but to stick to 'st_crop'. Going back to real life and my own data, I rerun both of your methods on a quite heavy shapefile (200k lines, 310 Mb). The 'st_intersect' way took 2622 vs 37.8 millisec  for the DT-way (on only 5 runs). Note that I have a 32 Gb RAM working station... I am afraid it will take forever to do what I want.

Comment: Depending on what it is that you are trying to achieve exactly, you might want to start thinking 'outside the box'. E.g. Can I use a raster based approach? Or you might want to start thinking about establishing a spatial database and do the queries using postgis. Or try using GDAL directly from the console... R really does not seem to be the correct tool for your task.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to overcome the problem described above. Instead of using 'st_intersects', one should use 'st_intersection' (see this [post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/289350/calculate-sum-of-line-lengths-in-r)), as it returns segments/area of lines/polygons intersecting with polygons. It took only 4 minutes to compute the sum of length of lines intesecting 4mio of 1-ha polygons (vs ages with alternative pathways).

```
library(sf)
#> Warning: le package 'sf' a été compilé avec la version R 3.5.3
#> Linking to GEOS 3.6.1, GDAL 2.2.3, PROJ 4.9.3
library(microbenchmark)
#> Warning: le package 'microbenchmark' a été compilé avec la version R 3.5.3

# load shapefile
nc = st_geometry(st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf")))
#> Reading layer `nc' from data source `D:\Program Files\R\R-3.5.2\library\sf\shape\nc.shp' using driver `ESRI Shapefile'
#> Simple feature collection with 100 features and 14 fields
#> geometry type:  MULTIPOLYGON
#> dimension:      XY
#> bbox:           xmin: -84.32385 ymin: 33.88199 xmax: -75.45698 ymax: 36.58965
#> epsg (SRID):    4267
#> proj4string:    +proj=longlat +datum=NAD27 +no_defs

# Define a bounding-box that mimic a mowing-window or area of interest
bb <- st_bbox(c(xmin= -79, xmax=-78,ymin= 34.5, ymax= 35.5))
bb_sfc = st_as_sfc(bb)
st_crs(bb_sfc) <- st_crs(nc)

# Compare cropping methods amon
TEST <- microbenchmark(
  crop_way = {
    # identify subset of nc that intersects with bbox
    isec = unlist(st_intersects(bb_sfc, nc))
    crop_nc <- st_crop(nc[isec], bb_sfc)
  }, 
  intersection_way = {
    inter_nc = st_intersection(bb_sfc, nc)
  }
)  

print(TEST)
#> Unit: milliseconds
#>              expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max
#>          crop_way 4.445589 4.533909 5.024318 4.701732 4.825892 13.62889
#>  intersection_way 2.687720 2.731952 3.029011 2.812023 2.904466  8.39283
#>  neval cld
#>    100   b
#>    100  a

sum(st_length(crop_nc),na.rm=T)
#> 1307555 [m]

sum(st_length(inter_nc),na.rm=T)
#> 1307555 [m]

Created on 2019-12-04 by the reprex package (v0.3.0)
```